# Помогите разобраться с удалением из БД

Tags: java, mysql

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = textField1.getText(); 
    updateQuery("DELETE from PR WHERE predmet_PR = " + s+";");
 System.out.println ("Запись удаленна");
            }
        });
```

Если хочу удалить по названию, то выскакивает ошибка:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'Third' in 'where clause'

хотя, если удаляю запись по ИД, то все нормально. Думал, может проблема что textField1 считывает лишние пробелы, сделал так:

```
char[] stroka = s.toCharArray();
                String s2="";
                for(int i=0; i<stroka.length; i++)
                {
                    if(!(Character.isWhitespace(stroka[i])))
                    {

                        String s1 = String.valueOf(stroka[i]);
                         s2 += s1;
                    }
                    else

                    continue;
                }
```

Все равно такая же ошибка. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = textField1.getText(); 
    updateQuery("DELETE from PR WHERE predmet_PR = '" + s +"';");
    System.out.println ("Запись удаленна");
}
```

Дело в том, что в запросе параметр, по которому ты ищешь соответствующую информацию в таблице, должен быть выделен кавычками, если он содержит текстовые данные.

Comment: Господи, а я тут такой ереси напридумал... Я думал что если мы его впихнули в переменную, значить нам кавычки не нужны, к примеру как при добавлений.А оно, при запросе надо.  Спасибо за быстрый ответ.

Comment: @Baffik чтобы окончательно отойти от ереси, надо срочно переходить на запросы с параметрами